# Java: add element after an element in the LinkedList

Tags: java, list

I want to add an element after an element in the list if list already contain that element otherwise I want to add this new element to beginning
 of the list.

Somehow below code is not working.

Any suggestions?

Does this approach correct performance wise?

```
public class HelloWorld
        {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
          LinkedList<Task> l =new LinkedList<Task>();

            l.add(new Task("a")); 
            l.add(new Task("b"));
            l.add(new Task("c")); 

            int index;

            if((index = l.lastIndexOf(new Task("a"))) != -1){
               l.add(++index, new Task("5"));
            }else{
               l.addFirst(new Task("6"));
            }        
            System.out.println(l);
      }
    }

    class Task{
     String value;

      Task(String v){
        value = v;
      }

      public boolean equals(Task t){
        return t.value.equals(this.value);
      }  

      public String toString(){  
       return this.value; 
      }
    }
```

**Output produces:** [6,a,b,c]

**Expected output:** [a,5,b,c]

Comment: Side note: you can find out how your program works eg. by using a debugger and setting break-points at the relevant lines.

Answer (score 5):

You are not overriding `Object#equals` in your `Task` class.

You need to parametrize it with `Object`, otherwise it's an overload.

That in turn doesn't allow your `new Task("a")` to be equal to `new Task("a")`, as `Object.equals` in invoked instead, and the references don't match.

This in turn will cripple your `lastIndexOf` invocation with unexpected results.

**Example**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO your code, i.e. based on the "value" field
}
```

If you're using an IDE (which I recommend), you will have features allowing to draft `equals` (and `hashCode`) implementations based on your desired properties.

Answer (score 3):

Your equals should look like that.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Task task = (Task) o;

    return value != null ? value.equals(task.value) : task.value == null;

}
```